# How to retrieve a flight number from boarding pass barcodes?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk

I've setup ZbarScanner with the aim to scan UK boarding pass barcodes. I'm getting the following string.

*Android Boarding pass String (I get a different result each time I scan)*

```
0164861544532221
```

*IPhone Boarding pass String*

```
M1MURRAY/BOB     EEMZ8KXXLPLCBDEZY8745 143 19A 581  10Z1364122498
```

The IPhone version of this app I'm attempting to port works fine, why are these strings different (does Zbar recognize boarding passes) and how do I decode my Android String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Boarding passes use a fairly unsual barcode format 'pdf417'. ZBarScanner does not support this. ZXing does have a setting specifically for pdf417.